# How to come out of blocked WinPcap API i.e pcap_next_ex()?

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker, wireshark, winpcap

In some application i am using WinPcap library to capture packets. I am developing application using WPF. Here i am calling pcap_next_ex() API in while loop with backgroundworker. here the pcap_next_ex is gets blocked, it's not responding.so our wpf application is hanging.How can i kill the background worker and how can i get out of Blocked API?

```
/*In WPF Application*/
    worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true; 
    worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);   
     worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProcessChanged);
     worker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
public void Start_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     worker.RunWorkerAsync();
  }
private void worker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 while(1)
  {
     status=getpacket();
    if(worker.cancelpending)
     {
          e.cancel=true;
          return;
     }
  }
 }
 /*In Vc++ dll*/
int status getpacket()
 {
     status=pcap_next_ex(pPcap,header, data);
 }`
```

My problem is here the pcap_next_ex() is blocking. It is not returning anything if i set to channel 56.

How can come out of this blockage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

libpcap/WinPcap's "read captured packets" APIs are, by default, blocking.

You should either:

1. Call `pcap_next_ex()` in a thread that doesn't do anything other than receive packets, so that other threads (including any UI threads you might have) don't block;
2. Put the `pcap_t *` in non-blocking mode with [`pcap_setnonblock()`](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#ga3f212141c80b59aad8ac535bb0178275), use [`pcap_getevent()`](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcapfunc.html#ga2c415e9192c7b18a81a02300ae6f2c02) to get, for the `pcap_t *`, a `HANDLE` you can use with [`WaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687025(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684242(v=vs.85).aspx) in an event loop, and, if that `HANDLE` reports that you can read packets, keep calling `pcap_next_ex()` until it fails - or just call `pcap_dispatch()`, which will process all packets that are available without blocking.

Comment: can u give example for usage of pcap_setnonblock () and pcap_getevent(). ?